# How do you add a custom application module to an ABP Project using the CLI?

Tags: abp

I have created a module (MyModule) that can be utilized by other projects. How do I add this module to another project using the cli?

When creating a project or module, there is an option for using a template from a local source. However, the 'add-module' command does not have an option like this, with or without the --new option. This command limits users to only VOLOSOFT ABP modules from this address https://abp.io/api/download/modules/.

The long solution is to manually drop my  into a project and add the appropriate 'DependsOn()'. I am looking for a shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new module using ABP UI and manually add the dependencies as the ABP documentation [here](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Module-Development-Basics) or using ABP CLI. I prefer to use the ABP CLI and for that use the below command:

```
abp add-module YourModuleName –new –add-to-solution-file
```

By the above command, ABP will do everything for you, but you will find an error when loading the solution again because there is a limitation for changing the solutions and projects references outside Visual Studio so you must solve the solution file first, and to solve it follow these steps:

1. **[important]** Backup your solution first or make sure that it is updated in your source-control.
2. Open the solution file with notepad or any other text-editor.
3. You'll find the newly added module projects in the top of your file and this is the issue. Just cut the lines and paste it in its right position in the solution file. I'm sure that you'll deal with that.

> This is my reference and its my own crack for this issue and I didn't
> follow any official documentation for that.